# How to add custom class as a component to gameobject in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

So I have a prefab which is Instantiated in run time, to that prefab I create and add another game object with components Image as a child. Now here how can I add a custom class data as component to the newly created child of prefab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to add your custom script to the game object on the scene, this custom script must be inherited from `MonoBehaviour`. After that, you can add your class do game object in the inspector (by clicking `Add Component` button, see image below) or from code by calling

```
gameObjToAddComponent.AddComponent<MyAwesomeComponentType>();
```

[image]